# TableLayout - Remove space between columns

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I'm having a problem with the `TableLayout`.

First, take a look at the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, there is a pretty big space in the middle of the `TableLayout`.
I don't know how to reduce the space in the middle, so that the `TableRows` will have more **Width** to cover.
And also, I want to reduce the space between a `TableRow` and the one below it.

I'm adding the views to the `TableLayout` programmatically.
Also, I've already set the '`layout_weight`' of the content of the `TableRow` to **1f**:

```
TableRow tr = (TableRow) new TableRow(mTableLayout.getContext());
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
NormalCard card = new NormalCard();
card.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, 740, 1f));
tr.addView(card);
mTableLayout.addView(tr, params);
```

XML declaration of the `TableLayout`:

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:dividerPadding="0dp"
            android:showDividers="none"
            android:divider="@null">
        </TableLayout>
```

How do I reduce the space in the middle of the `TableLayout`.
And also, How to reduce the space between a `TableRow` and the one below it.

Thank you upfront.

Comment: better to give the parameters in xml rather than giving in java

Comment: @Exeptional I have to use Java, because I'm using HTTP to get items and then add to the TableLayout.

Comment: just remove   android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" n check out

Comment: @Exeptional Also doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Please specify your table layout xml file you have just shown images.

try this if it works

```
android:shrinkColumns="*"  
android:stretchColumns="*"
```

in your TableLayout tag.

okay try to set padding as 0 to your table row if no of column in each row is same then specify table width as wrap_content.

Comment: I added the XML declaration. I also tried the attributes you mentioned and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this:

```
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```